# custom .vimrc settings in another file

Tags: vim

I want to keep my custom vimrc settings in a file in my Dropbox called `vimcustomvimrc.vim`

I did some searching and found this http://blog.mojotech.com/a-veterans-vimrc/  line below to put in my .vimrc file so that it will load my custom settings but its not working. can you please help?

file .vimrc contens below

---

```
set runtimepath+=~/Dropbox/vim
source ~/Dropbox/vim/vimcustomvimrc.vim
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is not needed if you only want to source that specific file; the `source` line is enough.

The `runtimepath` option allows you to add or remove *directories* to the default list of directories where Vim expects to find other default directories and `*.vim` scripts. If you don't keep any plugin or whatnot in `~/Dropbox/vim/` there's no need to change `runtimepath`.

Also, there's a lot of bullshit in that article: if I were you I would take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain your ~/.vimrc under version control using git version control system, for example: I have a [.dotfiles repo](https://github.com/voyeg3r/dotfiles). In it I have zshrc bashrc and a subfolder called vim. So I made somthing like this...

```
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/vim ~/.vim
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc
ln -sfvn ~/.dotfiles/zshrc ~/.zshrc
ln -sfvn ~/.dotfiles/bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

I think is a better solution because you can undo/redo some changes and can also add other good solutions shared on the internet easyly, things [like this solution made by Steve Losh](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/), or more specificlly [Synchronizing plugins with git submodules and pathogen](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) a great video made by  Drew Neil on this matter.

Comment: Describing your own usage is fine (if it's on topic, which it is) - adjusting your answer to be directly relevant to the question is better (i.e. `ln -s ~/Dropbox/vim/vimcustomvimrc.vim ~/.vimrc` etc.)